# Count the Number of a Specific Tag in an XML file - PHP

Tags: php, xml

If I have the following structure in an XML File;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <CstmrDrctDbtInitn>
    <GrpHdr>
      <MsgID>rBYEqfjzEU</MsgID>
      <CreDtTm>2014-07-01T12:36:15</CreDtTm>
      <NbOfTxs>2</NbOfTxs>
      <CtrlSum>400.4</CtrlSum>
      <InitgPty>
        <Id>
          <PrvtId>
            <Othr>
              <Id>IA1234567</Id>
            </Othr>
          </PrvtId>
        </Id>
      </InitgPty>
    </GrpHdr>
  </CstmrDrctDbtInitn>
</Document>
```

The above code represents one transaction between the `<CstmrDrctDbtInitn>` and <\CstmrDrctDbtInitn> tags. This file will be appended to include more transactions which will all start and end with a `<CstmrDrctDbtInitn>` and `<\CstmrDrctDbtInitn>` tags. I need to count the number of transactions in the file, so i basically need to count the number of `<CstmrDrctDbtInitn>` tags in the file. Any suggestions? Sorry if I am explaining this badly, confused!

I altered the following PHP code as suggested but no luck :(

```
$filename = date('Y-W').'.xml'; //2014-26.xml

//Check if a file exists
if (file_exists($filename)) 
    {
    $dom = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    global $NumberTransactions;
    $NumberTransactions = count($dom->CstmrDrctDbtInitn);
    // call xml appendFile function
    appendFile($filename);
    }
else 
    {
    // call xml createFile function
    createFile($filename);
    }
```

Comment: What you mean by "lines"?

Comment: show us more code. We don't know what `$GrpHdr` holds.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean to count the number of child nodes under GrpHdr - you could use SimpleXML:

```
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <CstmrDrctDbtInitn>
    <GrpHdr>
      <MsgID>rBYEqfjzEU</MsgID>
      <CreDtTm>2014-07-01T12:36:15</CreDtTm>
      <NbOfTxs>2</NbOfTxs>
      <CtrlSum>400.4</CtrlSum>
      <InitgPty>
        <Id>
          <PrvtId>
            <Othr>
              <Id>IA1234567</Id>
            </Othr>
          </PrvtId>
        </Id>
      </InitgPty>
    </GrpHdr>
    </CstmrDrctDbtInitn>
</Document>';

    $dom = simplexml_load_string($xml);

    // var_dump($dom->CstmrDrctDbtInitn->GrpHdr);
    echo count($dom->CstmrDrctDbtInitn->GrpHdr->children());
```

If you meant a variation you should be able to get a good clue of the structure by uncommenting that `var_dump` line and working through the object structure.

If you meant something else - give us a clue by telling us in detail what you wanted the count value to be based on your example data.

===================== UPDATED FOLLOWING CLARIFICATION BELOW=============

To count the number of CstmrDrctDbtInitn groups you can use the original example, but instead the count line would be:

```
echo count($dom->CstmrDrctDbtInitn);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, sorry for not being very clear, Im just confusing myself at this stage. The code I posted above has a opening tag of <CstmrDrctDbtInitn> and furthur down the code there is a closing tag </CstmrDrctDbtInitn>. This represents one transaction, the next transaction will begin and end with the same opening and closing tag. I need to count the number of transactions in the XML file. So I basically need to count the number of <CstmrDrctDbtInitn> tags which would equal the number of transactions..

Comment: Similar method would work - just last line to change, See updates to answer above.

Comment: I added code to my original as suggested but still no luck, thanks for your help anyway but its probably just me doing something wrong, it just doesnt seem to be counting as I am getting back zero.

Comment: If you want to post the full code perhaps we can help further?

Answer (score 0):

DOMXpath::evaluate() can use Xpath to count the nodes.

```
// create and load
$dom= new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

// register an alias/prefix for the namespace
$xpath->registerNamespace('iso', 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02');

// get the count
var_dump($xpath->evaluate('count(//iso:CstmrDrctDbtInitn)'));
```

Demo: https://eval.in/169122

Comment: This answer will break if the namespace URI changes. Use `getElemetsByTagName` instead - https://eval.in/169866

Comment: Namespace Uris are not supposed to change, they identify the format. If the namespace uri changes it is a different format - different data. However of course it is possible to ignore the namespace. The expression would be `count(*[local-name() = "CstmrDrctDbtInitn"])`.

Comment: The URI does not change (it never changes), however the namespace might (and therefore a different URI is used then). And it's not necessarily a different format, but a just in a new namespace. Like normally the tagnames do not change, the namespace does not change either.

Comment: The namespace should only change if it is a new/different format. If it is a new format the elements might have different meaning. That is the point of namespaces. It allows to use a unique and stable identifier for the format.

Comment: AFAIK the point of namespaces is to have same named elements but without conflicts. Whether or not the change of a namespace implies a change of format is out of scope of the specs and I'd say saying so is speculative. It must not map well onto expected changes in this (and other use-cases). Just pointing out that there are multiple angles to approach this counting question in a stable manner.

Comment: Your approach is less stable. The point of namespaces is to define the format the element belongs to. Like 'This element "title" is from the Atom feed format'. This allows for validation and yes it avoids conflicts. If you ignore the namespace (like getElementsByTagname() does, the result can include elements from other namespaces. So not only a change to the namespace (the format) can break your logic, but a change to the document, too. Just include a different format (namespace) with an element with the same name.

Comment: Stricness !== Stability - This lesson has been taught more than once with XML. And a change of format must not break logic necessarily. Just saying.

Comment: If it the format change is backwards compatible (like adding a new element) here is no need to change the namespace uri. If you're ignoring the namespace, you add more preconditions. You expect the document to be in a specific structure, not only to have elements in a specific namespace.